# The bool value always is always taken as false but its true in database? MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement, boolean

I have defined user(admin) type as 'bit' data type in my database. So if value is true it should go to a specific page otherwise it should return the same view. But whenever I pass object (adminObj) with different values the if statement only returns 'false' from database. Can somebody help where is the problem ?

here is my logic

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(tbl_Admin adminObj)
        { 
            studentDBEntities db = new studentDBEntities();
            var adminvar = db.tbl_Admin.Where(x => x.Email == adminObj.Email && x.Password == adminObj.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            var type=adminObj.Type;
            if (adminvar != null)
            {
                /*var isGlobal=*/
                if (adminObj.Type == true)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ListAdmin");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

> Values in Database-Table:

> When Type=1

[image: type is true at first place but false at if condition]

Comment: What about using a debugger or good old print statement to figure out what the (programming) type and value of adminvar.type is?  What is the database type?  Do you have to manually define the model mapping?  If so what it is for this object?

Comment: I have mssql, I am not using manual mapping.

Comment: Type has bool value in my model

Comment: Try it this way `if(type){...}`
You do not need to use `true` in `bool` values

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the logical error here. I was calling the login object instead of the object which was actually storing the fetched data. So I should call var `type=adminvar.Type;` instead of `var type=adminObj.Type;`

So The Corrected logic will be

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(tbl_Admin adminObj)
        { 
            studentDBEntities db = new studentDBEntities();
            var adminvar = db.tbl_Admin.Where(x => x.Email == adminObj.Email && x.Password == adminObj.Password).FirstOrDefault();
           
            if (adminvar != null)
            {
                
                if (adminvar.Type== true)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ListAdmin");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is type a reserved word?  Also, you should be able to use a single statement as you only have two outcomes.

Comment: Can you elaborate it.

Comment: Your gui colored the variable "type" the same color as other keywords.  It's usually a bad idea to use restricted names as variables as it could break any time in the future.   For the 2nd part, you either redirect or send a view, so I would write it as: 
if (adminvar != null and adminvar.Type == True) { return RedirectToAction("ListAdmin"); } return View();